# How to import and export contacts as vcard in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2, contacts, local-database

I have created a simple contact application using ionic 2. Now I want to import / export the contacts in my app. This contacts are saved in a local database created by my app, I am not using phones contact database. How can I achieve this? Is there any plugins available for doing this? I found [vcard-js](https://github.com/enesser/vCards-js) to export vcard but i don't know how to use them in ionic 2. Please help?